# Custom Control Doesn't Update in Visual Studio Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, windows-forms-designer

I'm creating a custom control that lays out radio buttons (No it doesn't have to be radio buttons.  I'm just trying to learn how to do this so I can make some more complex stuff down the road that may contain multiple lists of controls) which are added through the Items property (similar to some other controls).

I can build the project, drag this onto a form from the component panel and add radio buttons via the Items property. Unfortunately this is not updated in designer unless you either:

- Rebuild the project 2-3 times
- Close and reopen the form in designer

At first I had the logic that puts these on the form contained in the constructor after Initialize but that wasn't working so I moved to to Form_Load.

What am I missing?  The above options are just short term workarounds, not solutions.

RBLTest.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WFCL_Library
{
    public partial class RBLTest : UserControl
    {
        private List<RadioButton> _items;

        private int leftSpacing = 100;
        private int topSpacing = 25;

        public RBLTest()
        {
            _items = new List<RadioButton>();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RadioButtonList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int curLeftPos = 0;
            int curTopPos = 0;
            foreach (RadioButton rb in _items)
            {
                rb.Location = new Point(curLeftPos, curTopPos);
                rb.Size = new Size(85, 17);

                curLeftPos += leftSpacing;

                if (curLeftPos > this.Width)
                {
                    curLeftPos = 0;
                    curTopPos += topSpacing;
                }

                this.Controls.Add(rb);                
            }
        }

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public List<RadioButton> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return _items;
            }
            set
            {
                _items = value;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

RBLTest.Designer.cs

```
namespace WFCL_Library
{
    partial class RBLTest
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // RBLTest
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Name = "RBLTest";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(407, 44);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.RadioButtonList_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should't use the `Load` event or the constructor, because when you add the control with the designer tool an instance of the `UserControl` is created and the `Load` event is fired. In your case when this happens `_item` is still empty. Another issue is that there are some problems serializing a list, so I'd use an array:

```
public partial class RBLTest : UserControl {
    private RadioButton[] _items;

    private int leftSpacing = 100;
    private int topSpacing = 25;

    public RBLTest( ) {
        InitializeComponent( );
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility( DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content )]
    public RadioButton[] Items {
        get {
            return _items;
        }
        set {
            _items = value;

            int curLeftPos = 0;
            int curTopPos = 0;
            foreach ( RadioButton rb in _items ) {
                rb.Location = new Point( curLeftPos, curTopPos );
                rb.Size = new Size( 85, 17 );

                curLeftPos += leftSpacing;

                if ( curLeftPos > this.Width ) {
                    curLeftPos = 0;
                    curTopPos += topSpacing;
                }

                this.Controls.Add( rb );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result in the Form Designer:

[image]

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhh I just want to hug you right now, I spent so long toying with this with no luck finding anything on this subject with my poor google searches.  Do you happen to have a reference to an article discussing the issues with serializing generic lists in the designer?

Comment: @Mohgeroth You don't need another collection, you already have one in the Controls collection which is where your child controls have to live anyhow.

Comment: No sincerly I've never used a list and I don't know if it's possible, but if you need a list you can do in the property setter: `List<RadioButton> list = _items.ToList();`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are adding controls to the ControlsCollection only in the Load event. Here is a tutorial on creating container controls in WinForms that I googled:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9238/WinForms-Custom-Container-Control